# Django, displaying a view in an another view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to know if I can display a view inside another view with django.

This is what I tried to do:

```
def displayRow(request, row_id):
    row = Event.objects.get(pk=row_id)
    return render_to_response('row.html', {'row': row})

def listEventsSummary(request):
    listEventsSummary = Event.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:20]
    response = ''
    for event in listEventsSummary:
        response += str(displayRow('',event.id))
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

The output looks like what I was expecting but I have had to replace the request value with an empty string. Is that fine or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http response contains headers along with html, or anything else, so you can't just add them up like strings.

if you want to modularize your view function, then have sub-procedure calls return strings and then you can do it the way you propose

Probably in your case it would be better to put a loop showing rows into the template, then you won't need the sub-view and the loop in your main view.

```
def listEventsSummary(request):
    listEventsSummary = Event.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:20]
    return render_to_response('stuff.html',{'events':listEventsSummary})
```

and in stuff.html

```
{% for event in events %}
    <p>{{event.date}} and whatever else...</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yeah I was wondering how to remove the headers ;-)
thanks for the explaination